# Plotting results with missing categories in interaction with emmeans

Tags: r, anova, emmeans

I have a quite "messy data". I have a model with a interaction between two factors. And I want to plot it. So:

```
f1 <- structure(list(tipo = c("digitables", "digitables", "digitables", 
"digitables", "digitables", "digitables", "digitables", "digitables", 
"payments", "payments", "payments", "payments", "payments", "payments", 
"payments", "payments", "traditionals", "traditionals", "traditionals", 
"traditionals", "traditionals", "traditionals", "traditionals", 
"traditionals"), categoria = c("Advice", "Digital banks", "Exchange", 
"FinTech", "Insurance", "Investments", "Lending", "Payments and transfers", 
"Advice", "Digital banks", "Exchange", "FinTech", "Insurance", 
"Investments", "Lending", "Payments and transfers", "Advice", 
"Digital banks", "Exchange", "FinTech", "Insurance", "Investments", 
"Lending", "Payments and transfers"), Total = c(63L, 450L, 279L, 
63L, 36L, 108L, 567L, 549L, 63L, 450L, 279L, 63L, 36L, 108L, 
567L, 549L, 35L, 250L, 155L, 35L, 20L, 60L, 315L, 305L), Frequencia = c(44L, 
266L, 118L, 9L, 14L, 45L, 134L, 242L, 33L, 68L, 2L, 10L, 3L, 
8L, 11L, 78L, 27L, 226L, 142L, 10L, 20L, 45L, 300L, 245L), Perc = c(69.84, 
59.11, 42.29, 14.29, 38.89, 41.67, 23.63, 44.08, 52.38, 15.11, 
0.72, 15.87, 8.33, 7.41, 1.94, 14.21, 77.14, 90.4, 91.61, 28.57, 
100, 75, 95.24, 80.33), Failure = c(19L, 184L, 161L, 54L, 22L, 
63L, 433L, 307L, 30L, 382L, 277L, 53L, 33L, 100L, 556L, 471L, 
8L, 24L, 13L, 25L, 0L, 15L, 15L, 60L)), row.names = c(NA, -24L
), class = "data.frame")
# Packages
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(emmeans) #version 1.4.8. or 1.5.1
# Works as expected
m1 <- glm(cbind(Frequencia, Failure) ~ tipo*categoria,
          data = f1, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
l1 <- emmeans(m1, ~categoria|tipo)
plot(l1, type = "response",
        comparison = T,
     by = "categoria")
```

[image]

Using `by="tipo"` results:

```
# Doesn't work:
plot(l1, type = "response",
        comparison = T,
     by = "tipo")
Error: Aborted -- Some comparison arrows have negative length!
In addition: Warning message:
Comparison discrepancy in group digitables, Advice - Insurance:
    Target overlap = -0.0241, overlap on graph = 0.0073
```

If I use `comparison = F` as suggested by [explanation supplement vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/xplanations.html), it works. However, it does not show me the arrows, which are very important.

**Q1 - Is there a work around for it? (Or is it impossible due to my data?)**

As we can see from the last plot, there is a category with probability = 1 (categoria=Insurance and tipo=traditionals). So, I delete only this row of my data frame, and I try to redo the plotting, and results to me:

```
f1 <- f1 %>% 
  filter(!Perc ==100)
m1 <- glm(cbind(Frequencia, Failure) ~ tipo*categoria,
          data = f1, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
l1 <- emmeans(m1, ~categoria|tipo)
plot(l1, type = "response",
        comparison = T,
     by = "categoria")
Error in if (dif[i] > 0) lmat[i, id1[i]] = rmat[i, id2[i]] = wgt * v1[i] else rmat[i,  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

**Q2 - How to plot my results even when I have a missing level of one variable (with respect to another variable?). I would expect that the `Insurance` facet would have only have the `payments` and `digitables` levels (while the others remain the same).**

Comment: If you deleted that row from your data frame without refitting the model and recalculating EMMs, then all sorts of things will go wrong. What exactly is the problem with the first plot? You always have the option of ignoring that one comparison arrow.

Comment: The first plot is fine (with `by = "categoria"`). When I try the same "first plot" with `by = "tipo"`, I get an error, maybe because there are too many comparisons (and I want the arrows). For my `Q2`, I deleted that row and refitted the model and EMMs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please don't ever re-use the same variable names for more than one thing; that makes things not reproducible. If you modify a dataset, or a model, or whatever, give it a new name so it can be distinguished.

#### Q1

As documented, comparison arrows cannot always be computed. This is such an example. I suggest displaying the results some other way, e.g. using `pwpp()` or `pwpm()`

#### Q2

There was a bug in handling missing cases. This has been fixed in the GitHub version:

```
f2 <- f1 %>% 
    filter(!Perc ==100)
m2 <- glm(cbind(Frequencia, Failure) ~ tipo*categoria,
          data = f2, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
l2 <- emmeans(m2, ~categoria|tipo)

plot(l2, type = "response",
     comparison = TRUE,
     by = "categoria")
```

[image]

```
plot(l2, type = "response",
     comparison = TRUE,
     by = "tipo")

## Error: Aborted -- Some comparison arrows have negative length!
## (in group "payments")
```

Comment: PS -- I still don't see what's wrong with the plot in the OP. It shows a mean of 1, a CI of zero length, and a comparison arrow that doesn't overlap with anything. By deleting that observation, you are suppressing potentially useful information in the dataset.

Comment: Tks Russ! I agree. The plot in the OP is correct. Although, the comparisons in the table seems odd, that's way I removed that category (but I notify the client). Thanks. And your package is great! Saved my week